# For Loop in Java Script with SNS Message

Tags: javascript, for-loop, amazon-sns

I'm pretty new with Java Script and would need help with a problem with the following code snippet. Here I use a IF Statement to check the incoming SNS Message. If it is correct, I display the values from the message.

```
  else if (obj.intent === "list" && obj.message === 'success'){

            var innerHTMLval = '<table class="test"><tr><td class="test-loc"><img src="favicon.png" width="10%"></td><td class="test-loc"> View</td></tr>'
                + ' <tr><td class="forecast">'+ obj.artikel0+ '</td><td class="forecast">' + obj.stueckzahl0 + '</td> </tr>'
                + ' <tr><td class="forecast">'+ obj.artikel1+ '</td><td class="forecast">' + obj.stueckzahl1 + '</td> </tr>'
                + ' <tr><td class="forecast">'+ obj.artikel2+ '</td><td class="forecast">' + obj.stueckzahl2 + '</td> </tr>'
                + '</table>'            
                document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = innerHTMLval;            
 }
```

Everything works fine but now I want to know if I can work with a for loop that adds one line for each number.

My payload look like this:

```
{
    "intent": "list",
    "message": "success",
    "artikel0": "A",
    "stueckzahl0": 10,
    "artikel1": "B",
    "stueckzahl1": 10,
    "artikel2": "A",
    "stueckzahl2": 10,
    "artikel3": "C",
    "stueckzahl3": 10,

}
```

Is there a possibility to add the lines with a Foor loop depending on how many lines are in the payload?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a body variable and append to it like this

```
var body = "";
 for(key in obj){
   if((key.indexOf("artike") != -1) || (key.indexOf("stueckzah") != -1)){
     var end = (key.indexOf("stueckzah") != -1) ? '</td></tr>' :  '</td> ';
     var start =  (key.indexOf("stueckzah") != -1) ? ' <td class="forecast">' :  ' <tr><td class="forecast">';
     body+= start+obj[key] +  end;
   }
 }
var innerHTMLval = '<table class="test"><tr><td class="test-loc"><img src="favicon.png" width="10%"></td><td class="test-loc"> View</td></tr>'  
+ body +'</table>'
```

Comment: I have now one more variable. How can I add it also to the innerHTMLval? I add it to the if clause but how can I add it to the body?

Comment: it may be easier to push to an array of objects and then work with that. you can use the end detection to know when to move the the next array item.

Comment: can you explain to me what you mean? As I said, I'm still missing the experiences in js. I've added a new element based on your help. this will also print out but in a separate tr. I add it here: if((key.indexOf("material") != -1) ||(key.indexOf("artike") != -1) || (key.indexOf("stueckzah") != -1))

Comment: if you intend to place it in a different row, use another if statement  within the loop, so leave the previous as it is, and create the condition under it.

Comment: no i want the ne value material also in teh sam row like artikel and steuckzahl. I just dont know how to add it to the body...

Comment: do you need it to be in between the existing two or at the end?

Comment: at the beginning would be nice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201099/discussion-between-jidexl21-and-tim1234).

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
    "intent": "list",
    "message": "success",
    "artikel0": "A",
    "stueckzahl0": 10,
    "materiall0": "mat10",
    "artikel1": "B",
    "stueckzahl1": 11,
    "material1": "mat11",
    "artikel2": "A",
    "stueckzahl2": 10,
    "materiall2": "mat10",
    "artikel3": "C",
    "stueckzahl3": 10,
    "materiall3": "mat10",

}

var body = "";
 for(key in obj){
   if((key.indexOf("artike") != -1) || (key.indexOf("stueckzah") != -1) || (key.indexOf("material") != -1)){
     var isStart = (key.indexOf("artike") != -1);
     var isEnd = (key.indexOf("material") != -1);

     var end = (isEnd) ? '</td></tr>\r\n' :  '</td>';
     var start =  (isStart) ? '<tr><td class="forecast">' :  ' <td class="forecast">';
     body+= start+obj[key] +  end;
   }
 }
var innerHTMLval = '<table class="test"><tr><td class="test-loc"><img src="favicon.png" width="10%"></td><td class="test-loc"> View</td></tr>'  
+ body +'</table>'
```

output from body

```
/*

<tr><td class="forecast">A</td> <td class="forecast">10</td> <td class="forecast">mat10</td></tr>
<tr><td class="forecast">B</td> <td class="forecast">11</td> <td class="forecast">mat11</td></tr>
<tr><td class="forecast">A</td> <td class="forecast">10</td> <td class="forecast">mat10</td></tr>
<tr><td class="forecast">C</td> <td class="forecast">10</td> <td class="forecast">mat10</td></tr>

*/
```